# Horizontal table with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

How can I make table in `pgfplotstable` table form input file

```
A  B
1.0 20
1.1 21
1.2 22
1.3 23
1.4 24
```

looks like this one:
[image]

I trying to use `\pgfplotstabletranspose\loadedtable{input.dat}
\pgfplotstabletypeset\loadedtable`, but column names (A & B) parsing as floats (and gives error). And colnames counting starts from 0 (I need from 1).

And also is it posible to break (hyphenate) large horizontal tables?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. (Snippets tend to be much harder to answer.)

Comment: Sorry, next time I add

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error for the A and B column comes from the fact that `pgfplotstables` expects numerical data unless specified otherwise. To make the column handle strings, you have to set `columns/colnames/.style={string type}`.

To get the index to start at one, I would suggest to create a new column on the fly and using this for the column names with the key `colnames from=<name>`.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
A  B
1.0 20
1.1 21
1.2 22
1.3 23
1.4 24
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/index/.style={%
        create col/assign/.code={%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\entry{\pgfplotstablerow+1}%
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\entry}
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=index]\loadedtable{testdata.dat} 

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/colnames/.style={
        string type,
        column name={\#}
    }
]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplotstabletranspose]