# plotting data from rows instead of columns in latex

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

How can I use the addplot table command to select data from rows to be plotted instead of columns?

Thank you.. I tried that but still I got errors.. here is my script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[listofformat=empty]{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}



\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{plotData/PIP-TRUE-PD-TRUE/I2-I3-I4-I5-I6-0.1.dat}


\pgfplotstabletranspose\loadedtable{plotData/PIP-TRUE-PD-TRUE/I2-I3-I4-I5-I6-0.1.dat}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\loadedtable

\addplot[smooth,mark=*,white, draw=black] table[x=Rate,y index=8] {plotData/PIP-TRUE-PD-TRUE/I2-I3-I4-I5 I6-0.1.dat};
\addlegendentry{RR=0.1}
\end{document}}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22088/horizontal-table-with-pgfplotstable

Comment: Why don't you use `\loadedtable` in the `addplot`? The data file is not transposed, `\loadedtable` is.

Answer (score 8):

You can transpose the table first using

```
 \pgfplotstabletranspose\datatable{<filename>}
```

Then you can use the normal `\addplot table {\datatable};` command.

Comment: Thank you.. i tried that but still I got errors.. here is my script