# Draw a boxplot from a specific line of my data set

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, boxplot

I am new to PGFPlots and boxplot.
My data set is as below:

```
\begin{filecontents}{trial.dat}
1 12 3 2 25 6 21 8 6
11 2 23 14 15 16 17 82 92
11 22 39 43 51 61 79 80 9
1 22 3 48 35 66 17 28 99
\end{filecontents}
```

I want to draw a boxplot for, let’s say line number 2 of my data set
and I want that PGFPlots calculate for me the median, the lower quartile, etc.

As far as I understand how it works, I need to use the boxplot handler that
accepts a one-dimensional sample as input.
How could I say to boxplot that I want to take the one-dimensional sample
from and only from line number 2 of my data set?

(Of course, the next step for me will be to draw a boxplot for every line of my data set but it will probably be just a matter of loop).

Comment: [tag:pgfplotstable] provides some interfaces to read your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Symbol 1 already suggested in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344232/draw-a-boxplot-from-a-specific-line-of-my-data-set#comment844677_344232) PGFPlotsTable is able to transpose the data with the `\pgfplotstabletranspose` command (which also was posted by Jake already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183530/95441). Then you can just use a simple `\foreach` loop to draw the `boxplot`s.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\begin{filecontents*}{trial.dat}
    1 12 3 2 25 6 21 8 6
    11 2 23 14 15 16 17 82 92
    11 22 39 43 51 61 79 80 9
    1 22 3 48 35 66 17 28 99
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}                      % to transpose the table
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}        % to draw `boxplot's
    \pgfplotstabletranspose\mytable{trial.dat}  % transpose the data table
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
                % draw each originally row, now column as boxplot
                \addplot+ [boxplot] table [y index=\i] {\mytable};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]