# How to plot Box Chart with Normal Distribution Curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So far, I am very obsessed with Tikz though I am a newbie. I am wondering how to plot box chart with normal distribution curve as the picture below?[image]

This screenshot is from OriginPro Galley, I dont have the original data. 
So I assume data like this :

(0.12,0.33,0.34,0.54,0.68.0.67,0.78,1.02,1.11,0.45)
(0.13,0.34,0.37,0.33,0.41,0.45,0.47,0.43,0.67,0.87)
(0.31,0.42,0.35,0.64,0.72,0.47,0.67,0.87,0.58,0.56)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the data for the dots? Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hi, Schrödinger. I am so sorry for that. This screenshot is from OriginPro Galley, I dont have the original data,  and I assume a set of data.  I want to try it, but I dont know where to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether the points are Scatter plot. And it is easy to draw points. So I just plot the box chart with norm distribution curve.

It is mainly based on 
[Rotated Normal Distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452102/rotated-normal-distribution)
and some boxplot settings can be found in chapter 5.12.1 of 
[Manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{0.05}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=\offset+1/(\y*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\z)^2)/(2*\y^2));}]

\begin{axis}[samples=101,smooth,height=8cm,
boxplot/draw direction=y]
\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({1+gauss(x,1.2,0)},1+x);
\addplot+ [boxplot prepared={box extend=0.3,draw position=1, lower whisker=-0.5, lower quartile=0.1, median=0.5, upper quartile=.9, upper whisker=2}, ] coordinates {};

\addplot [domain=-3:3] ({3+gauss(x,1.2,0)},x);
\addplot+ [boxplot prepared={draw position=3, lower whisker=-0.5, lower quartile=0.1, median=0.5, upper quartile=.9, upper whisker=2,box extend=0.3}, ] coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, vic156, many thanks. The box and curve are produced by these points. And I assume a set of data,  could you please finish the rest part? I'll study it carefully. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, lerh. If you want to draw a box chart with data input,  [The link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344232/draw-a-boxplot-from-a-specific-line-of-my-data-set) may help. But the scatter plot needs more information. I mean each point needs a pair of coordinates. But the data you assumed only have a single row for each boxplot.