# Improve the visuals in the graph

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

After looking at some plots on [OriginLab](https://www.originlab.com/doc/Tutorials/GroupedBoxChart) which combine boxplots with the distribution curve and the raw data, I wanted to do something similar in PGFPlots. I found some interesting work already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524211/how-to-plot-box-chart-with-normal-distribution-curve). Building on this, I created the following plot. I see that the presentation of the plot and some visuals can be improved. The issue here is the distribution curves are too big. Would it be possible to do compress them? To plot these curves, I manually inserted the domain values along with the mean and variance of the respective datasets. Please find the code of the plots below:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\definecolor{saffron}{HTML}{FF9933}
\definecolor{brickred}{HTML}{F96302}
\definecolor{grenadier}{HTML}{D44700}
\definecolor{grandisorange}{HTML}{FFCF79}

\pgfplotsset{
    jitter/.style={
        x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+rnd*#1}}
    },
    jitter/.default=0.1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%--- PLOTTING DATA ---%

\pgfplotstableread[row sep = \\]{
x data \\
1 13.7219 \\
1 10.1599 \\
1 10.7791 \\
1 9.5097 \\
1 6.6125 \\
1 9.9981 \\
1 8.1011 \\
1 11.2725 \\
1 10.105 \\
1 12.0993 \\
1 10.5794 \\
1 11.7101 \\
1 9.9047 \\
1 9.8042 \\
1 7.6605 \\
1 8.3959 \\
1 10.2814 \\
1 5.2662 \\
1 9.861 \\
1 10.2249 \\
1 9.8222 \\
1 12.3537 \\
1 8.3699 \\
1 10.6791 \\
1 9.9997 \\
1 10.1496 \\
1 10.833 \\
1 12.2066 \\
1 6.4986 \\
1 10.0193 \\
1 9.1327 \\
1 8.4368 \\
1 9.162 \\
1 7.5179 \\
1 6.7939 \\
1 7.9497 \\
1 12.8426 \\
1 5.68 \\
1 12.1573 \\
1 8.3866 \\
1 12.8471 \\
1 7.6095 \\
1 8.569 \\
1 9.6969 \\
1 10.9593 \\
1 11.5845 \\
1 9.7342 \\
1 11.3692 \\
1 12.067 \\
1 8.6466 \\
}\dataA
\pgfplotstableread[row sep = \\]{
x data \\
2 10.6485 \\
2 12.1327 \\
2 8.3516 \\
2 6.8364 \\
2 9.087 \\
2 9.7096 \\
2 11.559 \\
2 12.0554 \\
2 8.6433 \\
2 12.6913 \\
2 9.6378 \\
2 7.6447 \\
2 8.1357 \\
2 8.5953 \\
2 6.7866 \\
2 4.49 \\
2 6.3017 \\
2 15.3823 \\
2 7.0121 \\
2 13.2661 \\
2 10.2045 \\
2 8.5268 \\
2 8.4672 \\
2 8.8128 \\
2 9.659 \\
2 7.7304 \\
2 10.6145 \\
2 8.4329 \\
2 10.7728 \\
2 9.4515 \\
2 8.1012 \\
2 9.4598 \\
2 8.2576 \\
2 9.2268 \\
2 6.8337 \\
2 7.8323 \\
2 10.8946 \\
2 10.1366 \\
2 6.3889 \\
2 5.5418 \\
2 9.3919 \\
2 9.3976 \\
2 7.3574 \\
2 11.4605 \\
2 7.8299 \\
2 8.0555 \\
2 9.3363 \\
2 8.2947 \\
2 8.9302 \\
2 4.9484 \\
}\dataB
\pgfplotstableread[row sep = \\] {
x data \\
3 11.1575 \\
3 6.3445 \\
3 7.6768 \\
3 6.8726 \\
3 6.1151 \\
3 8.0012 \\
3 7.3762 \\
3 7.2804 \\
3 4.5495 \\
3 8.7247 \\
3 7.1302 \\
3 5.6378 \\
3 9.6559 \\
3 7.6132 \\
3 7.7771 \\
3 7.182 \\
3 5.9942 \\
3 7.8322 \\
3 3.3087 \\
3 7.5138 \\
3 9.9824 \\
3 7.4416 \\
3 7.5475 \\
3 8.0151 \\
3 7.9198 \\
3 6.2829 \\
3 7.3886 \\
3 4.9581 \\
3 4.36 \\
3 6.6295 \\
3 7.805 \\
3 6.5626 \\
3 7.0912 \\
3 7.6083 \\
3 6.0897 \\
3 8.5777 \\
3 4.0153 \\
3 8.4225 \\
3 7.2019 \\
3 5.1663 \\
3 3.9603 \\
3 7.5764 \\
3 7.3596 \\
3 8.2149 \\
3 6.9772 \\
3 4.9117 \\
3 6.6025 \\
3 6.8943 \\
3 7.1555 \\
3 5.7075 \\
}\dataC


\begin{axis} 
    [boxplot/draw direction=y,
     xlabel={Classes}, 
     ylabel={Value},
     height=6cm,
     ymin=0,ymax=20,
     xtick={1, 2, 3},
     boxplot/box extend=0.1,    
     boxplot/whisker extend=0.03,
     every axis plot/.append style={fill,fill opacity=0.5},
     cycle list={{cyan},{orange},{black}}]

\addplot+ [boxplot] table [y index = 1] {\dataA};
\addplot+ [boxplot] table [y index = 1] {\dataB};
\addplot+ [boxplot] table [y index = 1] {\dataC};


\addplot+ [jitter=0.2, only marks, mark size=.7pt, xshift = 0mm] table [y index = 1] {\dataA}; 
\addplot+ [jitter=0.2, only marks, mark size=.7pt, xshift = 0mm] table [y index = 1] {\dataB}; 
\addplot+ [jitter=0.2, only marks, mark size=.7pt, xshift = 0mm] table [y index = 1] {\dataC}; 

\addplot+ [domain=5.266:13.7219, fill=none, smooth] ({1+1*exp(-pow(x-9.76243,2)/3.6622)},x);
\addplot+ [domain=4.489:15.3822, fill=none, smooth] ({2+1*exp(-pow(x-8.98630,2)/4.4150)},x);
\addplot+ [domain=3.309:11.1574, fill=none, smooth] ({3+1*exp(-pow(x-6.96339,2)/2.3290)},x);




\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are asking about at lot of different things, that you have not tried to do yourself. You should focus on one thing per question and describe what you have tried and what is causing you problems.

Comment: To decrease the width of the curves you can simply replace the 1 with a smaller value, e.g. 0.7: `1+0.7*exp(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you searching for something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
        jitter/.style={
            x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+rnd*#1}}
        },
        jitter/.default=0.1
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    /pgf/declare function={
        mu1    = 9.76243;
        sigma1 = 3.6622;
        mu2    = 8.98630;
        sigma2 = 4.4150;
        mu3    = 6.96339;
        sigma3 = 2.3290;
        factor = 1.5;
        amplitude = 0.75;
    },
]

    \pgfplotstableread{
        a        b        c
        13.7219  10.6485  11.1575
        10.1599  12.1327  6.3445
        10.7791  8.35160  7.6768
        9.50970  6.83640  6.8726
        6.61250  9.08700  6.1151
        9.99810  9.70960  8.0012
        8.10110  11.5590  7.3762
        11.2725  12.0554  7.2804
        10.1050  8.64330  4.5495
        12.0993  12.6913  8.7247
        10.5794  9.63780  7.1302
        11.7101  7.64470  5.6378
        9.90470  8.13570  9.6559
        9.80420  8.59530  7.6132
        7.66050  6.78660  7.7771
        8.39590  4.49000  7.182
        10.2814  6.30170  5.9942
        5.26620  15.3823  7.8322
        9.86100  7.01210  3.3087
        10.2249  13.2661  7.5138
        9.82220  10.2045  9.9824
        12.3537  8.52680  7.4416
        8.36990  8.46720  7.5475
        10.6791  8.81280  8.0151
        9.99970  9.65900  7.9198
        10.1496  7.73040  6.2829
        10.8330  10.6145  7.3886
        12.2066  8.43290  4.9581
        6.49860  10.7728  4.36
        10.0193  9.45150  6.6295
        9.13270  8.10120  7.805
        8.43680  9.45980  6.5626
        9.16200  8.25760  7.0912
        7.51790  9.22680  7.6083
        6.79390  6.83370  6.0897
        7.94970  7.83230  8.5777
        12.8426  10.8946  4.0153
        5.6800   10.1366  8.4225
        12.1573  6.38890  7.2019
        8.38660  5.54180  5.1663
        12.8471  9.39190  3.9603
        7.60950  9.39760  7.5764
        8.56900  7.35740  7.3596
        9.69690  11.4605  8.2149
        10.9593  7.82990  6.9772
        11.5845  8.05550  4.9117
        9.73420  9.33630  6.6025
        11.3692  8.29470  6.8943
        12.0670  8.93020  7.1555
        8.64660  4.94840  5.7075
    }\data

    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        xlabel={Classes},
        ylabel={Value},
%        height=6cm,
        ymin=0,ymax=20,
        xtick={1, 2, 3},
        boxplot/box extend=0.1,
        boxplot/whisker extend=0.03,
        every axis plot/.append style={fill,fill opacity=0.5},
        cycle list={{cyan},{orange},{black}},
        smooth,
    ]

        \foreach \i in {0,1,2} {
            \addplot+ [boxplot] table [y index=\i] {\data};
        }

        \foreach \i in {0,1,2} {
            \addplot+ [
                jitter=0.2,
                only marks,
                mark size=.7pt,
            ] table [
                x expr=\i+1,
                y index=\i,
            ] {\data};
        }

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{
            \addplot+ [
                draw=.!50,
                fill=none,
                domain=mu#1-factor*sigma#1:mu#1+factor*sigma#1,
            ] ({#1+amplitude*exp(-pow(x-mu#1,2)/sigma#1)},x);
        }

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and a huge cleanup of my code). When we set the amplitude to 0.75, does it distort any information presented in the graph? And what is the role of 'factor' in the code?

Comment: You are welcome. Since `amplitude` changes _all_ x-values I don't think that anything gets distorted. Regarding `factor` I suggest: Simply change its value and see what changes in the output ;)